# Class-level classmethod() can only be called on a method_descriptor or instance method

Tags: python, cython

util.py:

```py
import inspect

class Singleton(type):
    _instances=[]
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class MetaResult(Singleton):
    def __getattribute__(cls, name):
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

class Result(metaclass=MetaResult):
    @staticmethod
    def res_decorator(func):
        def funcwrap(*args, **kwargs):
            sig = inspect.signature(func)
            bound_sig = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            bound_sig.apply_defaults()
            #additional code to extract function arguments 
        return funcwrap
```

check_params.py

```py
from util import Result as _Result
from abc import ABCMeta as _ABCMeta

class paramparse(metaclass=_ABCMeta)

    @classmethod
    @_Result.res_decorator
    def parse_flash_params(cls, flash_config_path):
        #some code
```

Now, I cythonize the file check_params.py with following setup :

cythonize.py

```py
import os as _os
from pathlib import Path as _Path
from distutils.core import setup as _setup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext

files_to_compile = []

def cython_build(source_path):
    for dirpath, _, fnames in os.walk(source_path):
        for fname in [x for x in fnames if f.endswith('.py'):
            fname = _Path(fname)
            files_to_compile.append(fname)

    for e in files_to_compile:
        e.cython_directives = {'binding':True, 'language_level':3}

    _setup(name="Proj1",cmdclass={'build_ext':_build_ext}, ext_modules=files_to_compile)
```

cythonized as:
python cythonize.py --path C:\directory_where_check_params_exist

generates a pyd file on which the following unit tests were attempted to run:

Now, coming to the usage, in the unit tests:

unit_test_check_params.py

```py
from check_params import *    #getting error here , details outside the code

# unit tests written here
```

***check_params.pyx:112: in init check_params
    ???
E

TypeError: Class-level classmethod() can only be called on a method_descriptor or instance method.***

So when i debug this, the error appears as being caused because of the classmethod descriptor over decorator (def parse_flash_params) in check_params.py

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is `Singletonclass1.decorator1`? Please post something we can actually run, that actually reproduces the problem when run.

Comment: It is a decorator defined in Singletonclass1 which is a singleton class. I think we can start from just experimenting with a simple decorator first..

Comment: `@classmethod` works fine in Cython. A simple decorator works fine in Cython. A simple decorator combined with classmethod works fine in either order. This question is unanswerable. Read [mcve] and edit it.

Comment: Hi @DavidW, pls check the updated question. I tried to be as minimal as possible while still trying to make sense.

Comment: Your cythonize.py has a few syntax errors in so doesn't work. As does check_params

Comment: i have updated to remove the syntax errors. By the way no one on Github is interested in commenting on this issue i raised.. It has been open for a long time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still isn't a hugely helpful example in since the code you provide *still* doesn't actually work. However:

The case

```
@classmethod
@_Result.res_decorator
```

is definitely a Cython bug. In [the function `__Pyx_Method_ClassMethod`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/37070f3dc38930c2bcad81902184cce84fba7f0a/Cython/Utility/CythonFunction.c#L1233) Cython has a lot of type checks to ensure that the type is a method (a function defined in a class), while actually it only needs to be callable, and this should only really be checked at call time. As a quick workround you can edit the relevant internal Cython file (CythonFunction.c) to replace the lines

```
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
               "Class-level classmethod() can only be called on "
               "a method_descriptor or instance method.");
return NULL;
```

with

```
    return PyClassMethod_New(method);
```

This seems to me closer to what Python does, where it accepts any object and only checks for callability when the function is actually called.

In the longer term you should [report it as a bug in Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues) with an example that actually works to demonstrate the problem. This way it can actually be fixed. I don't think you need `Result` and the staticclass bit - `res_decorator` as an isolated function should demonstrate the problem.

---

The second possible order

```
@_Result.res_decorator
@classmethod
```

doesn't work in unCythonized Python either since the direct result of a `classmethod` decorator isn't callable. It only becomes callable when it becomes a bound method, which happens later. Therefore this isn't a bug in Cython.

---

Final addendum:

A cleaner workaround is to force Cython to use the builtin classmethod, instead of its own version that's causing bugs

```
try:
    myclassmethod = __builtins__.classmethod
except AttributeError:
    myclassmethod = __builtins__['classmethod']

class paramparse(metaclass=_ABCMeta):

    @myclassmethod
    @_Result.res_decorator
    def parse_flash_params(cls, flash_config_path):
        pass
```

The `try ... except` block is because `__builtins__` behaves slightly differently in Cython and in a Python module, which is fine because it's an implementation detail anyway.

Comment: I actually note that [you do appear to have reported the bug already](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3044) so fair enough...

Comment: yes @DavidW And i have edited the question to remove the syntax errors.

And you're right about everything. I tried to change the code, it worked. Your workaround for classmethod redefinition also works just as awesomely.

Comment: That workaround is going to cause a performance regression for most classmethods in cdef classes, because it's going to cause Cython to use the ordinary Python classmethod type instead of the one designed for C classmethods.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair point. A better workaround would probably be to only replace the code that sets the exception with `return PyClassMethod_New(method);`

Comment: Actually, rather than a performance regression, I think it might just cause a TypeError when the classmethod delegates to a PyMethodDescrObject that expects an instance instead of a class. (Replacing just the exception-setting code should avoid the problem, whether the problem is a performance regression or an error.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yes - tested it and you're right. I've updated the answer to recommend the better version instead. I don't think it should affect OP because they aren't using `cdef classes` but it's obviously worth getting it right